# How can I use spreadable props to retrieve nested object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, react-router

So I am attempting to dynamically create pages of content in React from a json file which works fine until I reach a nested object.

This is a snippet of one of my JSON objects stored in my JSON file. The link object is what I am having trouble accessing. I am able to retrieve the other properties perfectly fine.

```
{
    "core-topics": [
        {
            "id": "coding",
            "name": "Coding",
            "headerColour": "blue",
            "description": "Learn how to build your very own website!",
            "image": "https://www.bitdegree.org/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/what-is-a-web-developer.jpg",
            "link": [
                {
                    "id": "coding-item-one",
                    "name": "Java"
                },
                {
                    "id": "coding-item-two",
                    "name": "C++"
                },
                {
                    "id": "coding-item-three",
                    "name": "Python"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I have a template component which renders all of the content into HTML. This is just a simple template component. I have attempted .map on the link property but because nothing has been declared yet, I just get 'undefined or null property'. Logically I want do this in the 'Writer component' But cannot figure out how.

```
   render(){
    return(
        <Container>
            <HeaderImage headerImage = {this.props.image}>
                <ImageTextContainer>
                    <H1> {this.props.name} </H1>
                    <Stripe stripeColour = {this.props.headerColour}/>
                    <P> {this.props.description} </P>

                    {/* This is the nested object (I want to access the ID and name properties) */}
                    <p> {this.props.link}</p>

                </ImageTextContainer>
            </HeaderImage>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And this is how I am dynamically mapping all the data through each objects unique ID. Ideally I want a way to map the link object but cannot figure out how while using this approach.

```
const Writer = ({match: {url}, coreTopics}) => {
    return (
        <div>

           // This returns a page for each of the objects in my JSON file along with all the properties passed in from the template component
            <Route path = {`${url}/:topicId`} render = {
                ({ match }) => 
                <TopicHeaderCard {...coreTopics.find(topic => topic.id === match.params.topicId)}/>}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

So is there a way I can access the link objects propertise using this method? or is there another technique that would be more suitable for this approach?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check link before render, just add the verification !!this.props.link

```
 render(){
    return(
        <Container>
            <HeaderImage headerImage = {this.props.image}>
                <ImageTextContainer>
                    <H1> {this.props.name} </H1>
                    <Stripe stripeColour = {this.props.headerColour}/>
                    <P> {this.props.description} </P>

                    {/* This is the nested object (I want to access the ID and name properties) */}
                   {!!this.props.link && this.props.link.map((link)=>{
                    <div key={link.id}>    
                        <p>link.id</p>  
                        <p>link.name</p> 
                    </div>
                   })}

                </ImageTextContainer>
            </HeaderImage>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! Iv'e just tried this and it seems to work perfectly. You have saved me a long night of tearing my hair out!